# Passing the file data into function

Tags: java, file, snmp

Hi I have been trying to pass the `ipAdresses` which are in a file to a SNMP function which will perform a GET Operation. I am reading the file line by line and passing the data. But I am getting an error at `setAddress`, the program's works fine if I don't pass from the file. See in the code 1st line have commented ipAddress;

Code:

```
package com.snmp.discovery;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;

import org.snmp4j.CommunityTarget;
import org.snmp4j.PDU;
import org.snmp4j.Snmp;
import org.snmp4j.TransportMapping;
import org.snmp4j.event.ResponseEvent;
import org.snmp4j.mp.SnmpConstants;
import org.snmp4j.smi.Integer32;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OID;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OctetString;
import org.snmp4j.smi.UdpAddress;
import org.snmp4j.smi.VariableBinding;
import org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping;

public class Discover1 {

    private static String  port    = "8001";

    // OID of MIB CISCO-MGMT-MDM; Scalar Object = .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysDescr.0
    private static String  oidValue  = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0";  // ends with 0 for scalar object

    private static int    snmpVersion  = SnmpConstants.version1;

    private static String  community  = "public";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
            // Open the file that is the first 
            // command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
            // Get the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              // Print the content on the console
                Discover1.getDevice(strLine);
            }
            //Close the input stream
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void getDevice(String a) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SNMP GET Demo");
        System.out.println(a);
        // Create TransportMapping and Listen
        TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        transport.listen();

        // Create Target Address object
        CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
        comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
        comtarget.setVersion(snmpVersion);

        comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(a+"/"+port));
        System.out.println("------------");
        comtarget.setRetries(2);
        comtarget.setTimeout(1000);

        // Create the PDU object
        PDU pdu = new PDU();
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(oidValue)));
        pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
        pdu.setRequestID(new Integer32(1));

        // Create Snmp object for sending data to Agent
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);

        System.out.println("Sending Request to Agent...");
        ResponseEvent response = snmp.get(pdu, comtarget);

        if (response != null){
            System.out.println("Got Response from Agent");
            PDU responsePDU = response.getResponse();

            if (responsePDU != null){
                int errorStatus = responsePDU.getErrorStatus();
                int errorIndex = responsePDU.getErrorIndex();
                String errorStatusText = responsePDU.getErrorStatusText();

                if (errorStatus == PDU.noError){
                    System.out.println("Snmp Get Response = " + responsePDU.getVariableBindings());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: Request Failed");
                    System.out.println("Error Status = " + errorStatus);
                    System.out.println("Error Index = " + errorIndex);
                    System.out.println("Error Status Text = " + errorStatusText);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Response PDU is null");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Agent Timeout... ");
        }
        snmp.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is your catch clause. Don't catch ALL Exceptions. Actually look and see which ones can be thrown by your methods and catch those specific exceptions. Then, when one is thrown, it's less frustrating trying to see wtf is happening.

Comment: I have edited the above code please check; But still getting same error

Comment: Not so I can tell. Your main method still has a try catch block catching all exceptions, and your method still throws Exception. Until you fix that, you won't be able to tell what the problem is. Also, there's a stack trace from the exception being thrown I'm assuming, that information would be helpful.

Comment: getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 192.168.1.4 /8001

Comment: While calling function you are passing `strLine`. Try passing `StringUtils.trim(strLine)` (remove spaces)

Comment: Looks like extra space after IP address.

Comment: I have added IOException

Comment: @Ambrish: I am not getting the StringUtils.trim(strLine) can you please edit in the above code

Comment: You can also do `strLine.trim()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the error message it looks like that you have spaces in the file. When you pass the IP address directly there are no spaces and hence it works. You need to remove the spaces before using it.

Change following line

```
Discover1.getDevice(strLine);
```

Remove leading and trailing blank spaces. Like:

**Option 1:**

```
Discover1.getDevice(strLine.trim());
```

**Option 2:**

```
Discover1.getDevice(StringUtils.trim(strLine));
```

Reference: [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#trim%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

So this may not exactly be an answer, but it won't fit in the comments.

This is bad:

`catch(Exception e) { .... }`

ONLY do this if someone ELSE's method `throws Exception`. Also, punch that person if you can.

Your own method should NOT `methodName() throws Exception`. It should specifically `methodName () throws IOException` etc.

You should be doing `catch(IOException e) { ... } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {...}` etc

As you've seen, it makes it hard to troubleshoot if you don't know what kind of exception is thrown.

Finally, when asking for help with an Exception, you should generally include the stack trace. For example:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`
      `at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)`
        `at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)`
     `at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)`

This information is helpful with debugging.

Comment: Throwing Exceptions (or Throwables) should be avoided. But if you log an Exception (even with e.toString()) you get the specific type of Exception

Comment: I didn't mean that he should personally throw the Exception, I meant that his method shouldn't declare that it throws Exception, because that forces anyone using it to catch generic Exceptions.  Edited to make that clearer.